# Dataset's visual appearance is inconsistent

Tags: output-formatting, dataset, visualization

```
planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];
```

When I run

```
result1 = planets[All, "Moons" /* Keys]
```

[image]

I don't like the column appreance.I wan to show more value in a row,like:

```
moonMass = planets["Earth", "Moons", "Moon", "Mass"];
result2 = planets[All, "Moons", Select[#Mass > moonMass/2 &] /* Keys]
```

[image]

But I note the `Normal[result1]`'s structure is same to `Normal[result2]`'s totally:

[image]

But why the appearance is difference?

---

As the [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach),we should

```
planets[All, "Moons" /* Keys /* OutputForm]
```

Comment: I don't have that column appearance with your code. I Just have a gray rectangle...

Comment: @MirkoAveta Really?I'm in [v11.01](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-22-01-11-04.png).

Comment: A quick-and-dirty work-around: ``Block[{Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False}, Print@result1]``

Comment: @WReach I can use `planets[All, "Moons" /* Keys,;;]`,but I don't know what happen on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Dataset` visualizer estimates the display size of each element and then allocates a certain "budget" of display space to each.  Each element's layout is then adjusted to fit within that budget.  This adjustment uses many heuristics.  Those heuristics considers things not only data type, but also data size.

We can see some of those effects here:

```
makeDataset[n_] := 
 Table[Association[IntegerName[i] -> RomanNumeral@Range[i]], {i, n}] // Dataset

Table[makeDataset[n], {n, {5, 10, 13, 14}}] // Row[#, "  "] &
```

[image: visualization of datasets of different sizes]

Note how:

- the sublists are sometimes shown in full and sometimes elided
- the sublists are sometimes shown horizontally and sometime vertically
- the association itself is sometimes shown in full and sometimes scrolling controls

Unfortunately, it is difficult to influence these heuristic decisions reliably.  There various undocumented "magic numbers" which define the thresholds at which layout decisions change (e.g. `` TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionByteLimit ``, `` TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionLeafLimit ``, `` TypeSystem`PackageScope`$ElisionLengthLimit ``, `` Dataset`$ElisionThreshold `` and also some hard-coded values).  Also, the heuristics have changed substantially from release-to-release.

We can sometimes forcibly adjust the layout decisions by adding "wrappers" around certain values.  `OutputForm` is sometimes useful -- for example:

```
makeDataset[14][All, All, OutputForm]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
result1[All, OutputForm]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
result1[All, Shallow /* OutputForm]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Other useful wrappers include `Row`, `Grid`, `Panel` and so on... and even `Dataset` itself.  But unfortunately finding good work-arounds usually involves a lot of trial and error.

Perhaps some future release will offer more control.

Comment: So geek!Are you WR staff?

Comment: @yode For a while I was sure he was the official Wolfram Research presence on StackOverflow because of extraordinary depth of knowledge and [seniority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736101/618728), in addition to "WR," but as far as I know he is not, just really smart. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Inspiring! :)

Comment: If I had known when I joined StackOverflow that I was going to end up posting so many _Mathematica_ responses, I would have chosen a different nickname.  The _WR_ has confused enough people that I felt compelled to discuss it as a FAQ in my profile.  But, no, the only connection I have to WRI is that I use their software.  On the other hand, the only possible explanation for the vast number of high-quality postings from Mr.WRIzad is that it is the nickname for a collective within WRI ;D (@Mr.Wizard)